# imagick php rename a file error

Tags: php, imagick

I am reading a PDF with php imagick, my code is this:

```
$imagick->readImage('./file/number/pdf/archivo.pdf');
$result = $imagick->writeImages('./file/number/images/convert.jpg', false);
```

When i do this in my localhost the name is renamed by the new image: conver.jpg, convert-1.jpg, convert-2.jpg,etc ... But when I do this into my server, this create just one image, and overwrite the image and just remain the last one.

The server is ubuntu 12.04 and my localhost is and ubuntu 14.04

There is something could i do for rename all the images automatically?

Comment: We need more detail, where the $file_path come, and where the `$images_path` has set? And where is the `addImage` method?

Comment: If it is behaving differently on different machines it is almost certainly a difference in versions that is causing the problem. What versions are running on your dev machine and your server?